# How to sync perforce symlink and all it's symlinks and it's target(physical) file?

Tags: synchronization, perforce, symlink

Assuming I have a scenario that looks like this:-

```
workspace/a/a.txt -> ../b/b.txt
workspace/b/b.txt -> ../c/c.txt
workspace/c/c.txt
```

File `a/a.txt` is a symlink to `b/b.txt` and
`b/b.txt` is a symlink to `c/c.txt` and
`c/c.txt` is a physical absolute file.

My question is, is there a way in perforce, when i do

```
p4 sync workspace/a/a.txt
```

... it actually syncs over all the 3 files over to my local workspace?

If that is not doable thru perforce, what is the best approach of achieving that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it? That is, have you added `a/a.txt` (as a symlink), `b/b.txt` (as a symlink), and `c/c.txt` (as a file) to Perforce, then made a new workspace, then sync'd that workspace? Note that you'll have to sync **all three** files; just sync'ing `a/a.txt` will obviously sync only that one, not the others.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Of course syncing all 3 files will work. But what i wanted to do is, when I do a sync on `a.txt`, it will automatically sync over `b.txt` and `c.txt` as well. I looked thru the `sync` help options, and it does not seem to have an option that does that. I wondering have anyone done this before.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I don't know of such an option, but I think your question is more clearly described now.